# Node save not saving custom fields!

Tags: 7, nodes

I have scoured this site and tried to find examples that I could use and all seem to show the same thing, the code I am writing fits to the right pattern and yet its just not saving!

When submitted the content is created but only the title is saved all the rest is left blank, this is extremely frustrating as I have tried many combinations to try and sort this out PLEASE! any help or pointers are GREATLY appreciated:

```
           global $user;
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'client_account';
    $node->title = $form_state['values']['groupName'];
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->name = $user->name;
    $node->comment = 0;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_UNDEFINED;
    $node->is_new = True;
    $node->path = array('alias' => 'accounts/' . $form_state['values']['groupName']); // Setting a node path
    node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.



    $node->group_group[$node->language][0]['value'] = 1; //this is a checkbox value on or off
    /*
     * The rest of the fileds in the content type are actually text fields
     */
    $node->field_company_contact[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['contactName'];
    $node->field_client_email[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['clientEmail'];
    //not implimented yet but requires a default value
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'set body with page values';
    //not implimented yet but requires a default value
    $node->field_company_logo[$node->language][0]['value'] = "/images/logo.png";
    $node->field_website[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['website'];
    $node->field_address_line1[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine1'];
    $node->field_address_line_2[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine2'];
    $node->field_address_line_2[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine3'];
    $node->field_region[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['county'];
    $node->field_post_code[$node->language][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['postCode'];
    //Organic groups fields
    $node->og_description = 'A group managed by ' . $user->name;
    $node->og_register = 0;
    $node->og_directory = 1;
    $node->og_private = 1;
    $node->og_selective = 3;
    //create the node
    /*
     * drupal_printd($var, $title, $die=false)
     * is a fucntion I added for on the fly debugging
     */
    drupal_printd($node, "original_node");
    $node = node_submit($node);
    drupal_printd($node, "node save");
    $node = node_save($node);
    drupal_printd($node, "result");
    drupal_goto("accounts");
```

I hope someone can see why it is not saving as it just IS NOT!!

Comment: Do you have a multilingual site? If not it should be `$node->language = LANGUAGE_UNDEFINED;`

Comment: No I dont, but this version of the code is the latest iteration, it was originally set as undefined but this made no difference to the out come, but thanks for answering so quickly!  I will change it back now and edit the code example

Comment: If anyone wants to know what the drupal_printd() debugging data displays it is basically a print_r wrapped in <pre> tags that adds a title at the top and a dashed line at the end e.g.
    ----------start of title--------
    title =>Array { "key"=>"value"}
    ----------end of title--------

Comment: try this $node->body['0']['value'] = 'set body with page values';

Comment: Im afraid that didn't work either